# Android ADT bundle [install new software]

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-adt

I've just downloaded the Android ADT bundle (eclipse + Android SDK) from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) and I tried to install new software from

Help --> Install new software...

but there's always an error (an exception) that occur. The repository I'm trying to load is http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse-preview/ and the error is

[image: exception]

I'm not behind a proxy and I don't understand what the problem is. I also tried to follow different answers found here on stackoverflow, but the problem is still with me! Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

Paste this url - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to download ADT.

Comment: Paste that url gives me the same exception I described in the main post.

Answer (score 2):

Your IP address may be blocked by Google.
Change your IP and Try again.
You can use the software: Freegate

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are trying to use doesn't exist. If you click the link you are taken to a 404 error.

Also try downloading the ADT from the link here https://dl.google.com/dl/android/eclipse-preview/index.html. This requires a manual install though.

Comment: As you can see from the image I posted, I've already changed in http protocol.

Comment: The problem is not the repository itself. With all repository, also the official eclipse version repo, the exception happen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press the Add button
2. Name : ADT Plugin
3. Location : Paste the URL